# Coinjoin API server possible?

Tags: api, coinjoin

Is there a protocol limitation (I suspect there is) that does not enable transactions across different platforms to access a 3rd party remote server (Chaumian server?) through API and create a coinjoin every let's say 2 minutes or 100 users from all platforms/wallets? If someone implemented such a server, this would highly increase coinjoin liquidity and privacy.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in particular stopping exchanges from using CoinJoin to construct transactions with other exchanges, but rather **there does not appear to be any demand for this**.  For example both JoinMarket and Wasabi[<sup>1</sup>](https://wasabiwallet.io/swagger/index.html) have APIs that could be used.

In the future this situation could change if something like [Schnorr signature aggregation](https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/the-power-of-schnorr-the-signature-algorithm-to-increase-bitcoin-s-scale-and-privacy-1460642496) capabilities are adopted by Bitcoin. In that situation, CoinJoin transactions could be noticeably smaller (and therefore cheaper) than many separate single-output transactions.  This still seems very unlikely though as the exchanges are more likely to [simply batch their own transactions](https://bitcointechtalk.com/saving-up-to-80-on-bitcoin-transaction-fees-by-batching-payments-4147ab7009fb) rather than working with other exchanges.

Until a significant percentage of users demand privacy, exchanges are unlikely to change anything.  There may also be regulatory issues with them providing such an option.